# Stop automating zoom from field inside scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, scrollview, zooming

Hi I'm using WKWebView and I'm loading an iframe which have filed for typing in it. When you click that field the screen is automatically zoomed to the field. How to prevent that zoom?

```
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 0
```

not working with this code. Another suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

this helped me